# DIY Zeppelin/Blimp

Tags: diy, blimp

Hi

I have designed a low cost blimp (not yet constructed one) and it uses PVC pipes and a mesh...but i need some info. regarding the extendable pole...a friend suggested an outdoor umbrella's extendable pole... any other ideas?

[EDIT]

also what material windshield and can any toy making fur be used?

Can someone please tell me what components are part of a blimp and what kind of mic is present inside one and what does the handle/grip do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This classic site](https://pantherfile.uwm.edu/type/www/audio-reports/DIY_ShockZep_4_NT1A_ORTF/DIY_ShockZep_4_NT1A_ORTF.html) (and [this](https://pantherfile.uwm.edu/type/www/audio-reports/DIY_NT4_3inchPVC_ShockZep/DIY_NT4_3inchPVC_ShockZep.html), and [this](https://pantherfile.uwm.edu/type/www/audio-reports/car-wash-mit-zeppelin/quickie-car-wash-zeppelin.htm), and [this](https://pantherfile.uwm.edu/type/www/audio-reports/QuadPacConstruction/)) will give you DIY ideas galore.

Comment: @NoiseJockey- https://pantherfile.uwm.edu/type/www/audio-reports/DIY_NT4_3inchPVC_ShockZep/DIY_NT4_3inchPVC_ShockZep.html

is quite similar to my design.. yet to build, will scan and upload soon

Answer (score 4):

Use a painter's pole for your boom.

For the wind jammer / dead cat, I've read that long fur fabrics (like you'd make a stuffed animal's hair out of) works, and I believe that's all [Redheads](http://www.redheadwindscreens.com/) are.

Inside the blimp, you'll need something to act as a shock mount or every tiny movement will be transferred into the microphone.  The purpose of the blimp is to create a bubble of still air, or as close to it as possible, without reducing the incoming sound, as well as protecting your mic from bumps and small amounts of rain.  The handle is there to allow you to hold the blimp in your hand and aim it like a pistol (thus, pistol grip), giving you more control of your mic.

There's usually a shotgun mic inside of them (to be frank, if you didn't know that, I think you're putting the cart miles ahead of your horse), but I'm sure people have used other mics as well (small diaphragm condensers come to mind).

Comment: hi, thanks..
i know its a shotgun mic, but do they all have same dimensions i.e. length and width? im trying to build for a shotgun assuming length is 15"

i will post my drawings soon

Comment: i said "I have designed a low cost blimp (not yet constructed one) "

Comment: For shotgun lengths, I know they're not all the same but I'm not sure what the various dimensions are.

And it sounds like you're doing your research before you start doing anything.  Measure twice, cut once... you're on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

Hey, I thought you said that you've already designed one....you may now have to redesign it once you know the requirements - so here's a [windshield](http://audiofieldrecordings.wordpress.com/2010/05/21/large-microphone-windshield-an-alternative-approach/) I built which works well, followed by an adaption to an existing [blimp](http://audiofieldrecordings.wordpress.com/2010/09/09/rode-nt5-microphones-modified-ortfnos-recording-technique/) with photos showing the suspension system and some of the mics inside.

For the boom pole I make use of a telescopic camera monopole which is visible in the blimp post above.

Just a few of many different arrangements, depends on your individual requirements. It's fun experimenting, that's the way we learn, so just go ahead, build, adapt, rebuild, modify......
Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Extendable pole a.k.a. camera monopod. The Manfrotto 560B has retractable tripod feet which live inside the pole and can be pulled out and screwed into position when needed. Downside: it's quite heavy.

Manfrotto also make thread adapters that might come in handy too, eg their 1/4" to 3/8" adapter, model number 088.

Edit: Sonic Fields beat me to it with his monopod suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

here is what my girlfriend build for me :)

[image]

You can check out the rest of the photos [here](http://flic.kr/s/aHsjBqCJuw)